# How do I install JSBuild plugin and get going?

Tags: html, c++

I am working in Notepad ++. I am having a go at getting familiar with a-frame. Creating a basic simulator walkthrough VR type thing I can run around in.

I was taught to begin with this:

```
<!-- Production Version, Minified -->
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.3.2/aframe.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<a-scene>
    <a-box color="#2ff256" width="4" height="14" depth="2"></a-box>

</a-scene>
</body>
```

Doesn't seem to work when I run it through (open it) in Chrome.

Comment: When you say 'doesn't seem to work' can you describe what it does do?  Or doesn't it do anything at all?

Comment: I dont see why you tagged this C++, did I miss something obvious? (P.S: I'm pretty sure you meant Notepad++ *not* Notepad C++)

Comment: Thanks guys for replying.

LordWilmore - What I mean is, when I run it in the browser, I just get the html code instead of the basic box shape I should be able to interact with. I am not sure if I have installed the JS Build properly.

Borgleader - I meant to say Notepad++. sorry!

Comment: Also, I need to ask if I need to put the js script file on my computer in the right folder, or whether that is even appropriate. Its all chinese to me.

The file I downloaded was this: aframe.min.js

What do I do with it?